# Why does Solr store the original/pre-analysis content of a field rather than just its index?

Tags: solr, lucene

This question kind of makes it clear that I am new to Solr and all of its wonderful features. I apologise for my noobness.

But why does Solr store the original content in addition to the index? It just seems wasteful. I do realise that it stores the original content only if the field has the property `stored="true"`.

Where does it store the original content? Does it reference the actual document somehow?

Also, Is there any way to directly view the index files saved by Solr for each collection?

Links will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Solr didn't store the text, it wouldn't be able to actually return the text it found - making it impossible to do stuff like highlighting, or build an application that uses the results from Solr directly. You'd have to look up the actual content somewhere else for each and every result, which might not be what you want (and that content might not be available, for example if you're building a search engine - it wouldn't really be effective to retrieve each page in a search result to get the relevant information anyways).

You can read up on the index file format in [the API documentation for the Lucene60 codec](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene60/package-summary.html), the stored fields are stored using [the stored fields format](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene50/Lucene50StoredFieldsFormat.html). These fields live in the .fdt files in your index directory.

The index files are usually available in the `data/index/` directory under the collection / core on disk:

```
data/index$ ls
_zq.fdt             _zr.fdx             _zs.si
...
```

Comment: What do the .fdx and .si files store then?

Comment: So, the UpdateRequestProcessor is responsible for the content that is stored in a field and the analyzer is responsible for what and how that content is saved in the index after tokenization. Is this correct?

Comment: The UpdateRequestProcessor is an optional chain of processing that happens before the field data is handed over for indexing, yes. It isn't really responsible, but it's a way you can add additional parsing and scripting before it's handed over for analysis / tokenization / filtering. The URL [linked in the answer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene60/package-summary.html#File_Naming) for the apidoc specifies each file type: `.si: Stores metadata about a segment`, `.fdx: Contains pointers to field data`.